# Margin of the content from the top is changed after run the project

Tags: ios

[image]

This is the picture of storyboard.

[image]

Second picture is on simulator. i used `UIScrollView` in it.

Comment: did you uncheck scroll view insets

Comment: cause you've put it into `UINavigationController`

Comment: @EICaptain Thanks man problem is solved, but i have one issue. After uncheck insets scrolling is not working now.

Comment: then there may be other cause...Did you set code or autolayout for scrollview....@SandeepChaudhary

Comment: disable the navigation bar programmatically, `    self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = YES;
`